# webSocketServer node.js how to differentiate clients

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am trying to use sockets with node.js, I succeded but I don't know how to differentiate clients in my code.
The part concerning sockets is this:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server, 
    wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message); 
        ws.send(message);
    });
    ws.send('something');
});
```

This code works fine with my client js.

But I would like to send a message to a particular user or all users having sockets open on my server.

In my case I send a message as a client and I receive a response but the others user show nothing.

I would like for example user1 sends a message to the server via webSocket and I send a notification to user2 who has his socket open.

Comment: How do _you_ define which connection is "user1" and which is "user2"?

Comment: I don't know realy, I thought to give a kind of socketSession to the user when connecting

Comment: Well, as soon as you know the _user identity_ of the connection (e.g. when your user sends his username as a message), you can store a named reference to it in a dictionary (e.g. `connections[username] = ws`) and after that, elsewhere, you can do something like `connections[username].send(message)`

Comment: If your need is not quite to target an individual user, but rather a group of users (could be a group of 1) silo'ed into "rooms", you could use the socket `join()` and `broadcast()` methods. See some discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846174/dynamic-rooms-with-socket-io-and-node

Comment: Thanks It works fine registring all my ws in an array :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can simply assign users ID to an array CLIENTS[], this will contain all users. You can directly send message to all users as given below:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
    wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080}),
    CLIENTS=[];

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    CLIENTS.push(ws);
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        sendAll(message);
    });
    ws.send("NEW USER JOINED");
});

function sendAll (message) {
    for (var i=0; i<CLIENTS.length; i++) {
        CLIENTS[i].send("Message: " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you send clients' unique ID back and forth, you can also get the source client of the message.

Comment: This solution cannot be scaled because variable CLIENTS lives inside a single process of NodeJS. Even if we harness multiple cores by forking multiple processes, CLIENTS is not a shared memory allocation, each process maintains its own list of CLIENTS. Hence, it would require subsequent connections to talk to the same process.

Comment: could you post client side as well?

Comment: @KhanhHua could you please provide a scalable solution

Comment: @Khanh Hua I absolutely agree. I'm struggling with this right now. Can anyone suggest how this might be implemented so multiple workers in a cluster could all share a collection of web sockets and act upon them?

Comment: I'm thinking of using REDIS to store web socket objects or something but I don't know if that's a half baked idea or not.

Comment: Cache systems like Redis can only flattened store structures, for example connection ID or handle ID of connected clients. When a client connects, a socket representing the client comes to exist in the process of the server. When the process dies, socket is closed, connection is broken. This client socket cannot be shared among processes (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: How would you get the clients information, such as their IP address?

Comment: You can use Redis pub-sub and make a "publish" channel which every server you have listens to. Whenever a message is published on that channel, every server broadcasts to all of their clients. Simple as that.

Comment: Per [the docs](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md), `WebSocketServer` has a `clients` property that tracks current clients for you.  The docs also give an example of iterating over that collection to send a broadcast message to each client.

Comment: Simple test case this would fail. If user has multiple devices connected at the same time, you'd only be able to send message to a single device.

Comment: @MehmetAVŞAR, how can we send back the assigned ID to client?

Comment: @KhanhHua SO is not for providing full-scale solutions but rather short snippets of code to help you in the right direction. What you are talking about is not related to the question asked. That is a different subject entirely.

Comment: This solution will lead to memory leak eventually.

Comment: @link89 Hi could you please elaborate? Thank you!

Comment: @mehov It keeps pushing new `ws` instance to `CLIENTS` without removing them at some point, which will exhaust the memory after handle too many connections.

Answer (score 143):

In nodejs you can directly modify the `ws` client and add custom attributes for each client separately. Also you have a global variable `wss.clients` that can be used anywhere. Please try the following code with at least two clients connected:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpsServer
});


wss.getUniqueID = function () {
    function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4();
};

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
    ws.id = wss.getUniqueID();

    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
        console.log('Client.ID: ' + client.id);
    });
});
```

You can also pass parameters directly in the client connection URL:

```
https://myhost:8080?myCustomParam=1111&myCustomID=2222
```

In the connection function you can get these parameters and assign them directly to your `ws` client:

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {

    const parameters = url.parse(req.url, true);

    ws.uid = wss.getUniqueID();
    ws.chatRoom = {uid: parameters.query.myCustomID};
    ws.hereMyCustomParameter = parameters.query.myCustomParam;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without mutating `ws`? When doing `ws.clients.values()`, is there a way to grab the request off of that list?

Comment: +1 for the answer.
Adding references supporting it:

https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/859

Comment: This is was awesome, thanks! I am using the websocket library (instead of ws) so I had to use `req.resourceURL` This includes a parsed querystring as part of the object so you can just `req.resourceURL.query.myCustomParam`

Comment: In TypeScript, I get a `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'WebSocket'` error. Is there a way to do this without casting to `any` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type)?

Comment: If any newbie is wondering, `url` at `url.parse()` is a built-in Nodejs module. In order to get this line to work add `const url = require('url')` to your script

Answer (score 17):

you can use request header 'sec-websocket-key'

```
wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
  ws.id = req.headers['sec-websocket-key']; 

  //statements...
});
```

Comment: How about sec-websocket-key collision?

Comment: Wonderful! Tank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

[This code snippet](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/wiki/How-to%3a-List-all-connected-sessions-&-Communicating-with-a-specific-session-only) in Worlize server really helped me a lot.  Even though you're using ws, the code should be easily adaptable. I've selected the important parts here:

```
// initialization
var connections = {};
var connectionIDCounter = 0;

// when handling a new connection
connection.id = connectionIDCounter ++;
connections[connection.id] = connection;
// in your case you would rewrite these 2 lines as
ws.id = connectionIDCounter ++;
connections[ws.id] = ws;

// when a connection is closed
delete connections[connection.id];
// in your case you would rewrite this line as
delete connections[ws.id];
```

Now you can easily create a broadcast() and sendToConnectionId() function as shown in the linked code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: A `for in` loop will need to be used to broadcast, as opposed to a standard for loop, as there are "holes" in the (associative) array.

Answer (score 8):

It depends which websocket you are using. For example, the fastest one, found here: https://github.com/websockets/ws is able to do a broadcast via this method:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
   wss = new WebSocketServer({host:'xxxx',port:xxxx}),
   users = [];
wss.broadcast = function broadcast(data) {
wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
  client.send(data);
 });
};
```

Then later in your code you can use wss.broadcast(message) to send to all. For sending a PM to an individual user I do the following:

(1) In my message that I send to the server I include a username
(2) Then, in onMessage I save the websocket in the array with that username, then retrieve it by username later:

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

  ws.on('message', function(message) {

      users[message.userName] = ws;
```

(3) To send to a particular user you can then do                                            users[userName].send(message);

Comment: could you provide any link to code where you include username?

Comment: On the client, when you send a message you can create a JSON object then stringify it like so:    var sendObject = {userName:"Tim",pm:true,message:"how are you?"}; ws.send(JSON.stringify(sendObject));   Also, in Einaros you can send a json payload in the headers, like so: WS.open(uri, [JSON.stringify({userName:"Tim"})]); Then you can parse it on the server using ws.upgradeReq.headers and can turn the string back into its object via JSON.parse. I have used this method to create user groups, but it can also be used to store a user array.

Comment: I have a similar issue but could not solve it, could you have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535700/websockets-send-messages-and-notifications-to-all-clients-except-sender

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan If you think my answer is correct could you please upvote. Thanks. I have commented on your plunk and found one spelling error that might be affecting things.

Comment: sure I will, first I need to check it tommorow.

Comment: Show us how & where you push to users[], otherwise, this answer doesn't answer the question. It just shows how to broadcast to all clients, not individual ones. -1

Answer (score 6):

I'm using fd from the ws object. It should be unique per client.

```
var clientID = ws._socket._handle.fd;
```

I get a different number when I open a new browser tab.

The first ws had 11, the next had 12.

Comment: I think the file descriptor, fd, could be reused if a user leaves and another user joins... Essentially they might get recycled

Comment: if use leaves you can delete it from your session, and when new one joins even with the same number there will be unpopulated key in your sessions table

Comment: probably there might be problem that on disconect the _handle will be gone and you can't remove it from the table, probably you could save the handle inside the ws?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the connection object. It has built-in identification for every connected client; you can find it here:

```
let id=ws._ultron.id;
console.log(id);
```

Comment: How do you know Ultron.id is unique? I can't find anything related to that.

Comment: Try it on your own using different connections.

Comment: `ultron` is removed as a dependency of `websockets/ws` in releases 5.1, 5.0 and 4.1, last January. When using these (or later) versions, `ws._ultron` will no longer exist.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution here could be appending the deviceId in front of the user id, so we get to separate multiple users with same user id but on different devices.

`ws://xxxxxxx:9000/userID/<<deviceId>>`

Answer (score 1):

Use a global counter variable and assign its value for every new connection:

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server});
let count_clients = 0;
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws){
    ws.id=count_clients++;
    console.log(`new connection, ws.id=${ws.id}, ${ws._socket.remoteAddress}:${ws._socket.remotePort} #clients=${wss.clients.size}`);
    ws.on('close', req => {console.log(`disconnected, ws.id=${ws.id}, ${ws._socket.remoteAddress}:${ws._socket.remotePort} #clients=${wss.clients.size}`);});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

By clients if you mean the open connections, then you can use `ws.upgradeReq.headers['sec-websocket-key']` as the identifier. And keep all socket objects in an array.

But if you want to identify your user then you'll need to add user specific data to socket object.

Answer (score 0):

If someone here is maybe using [koa-websocket](https://github.com/kudos/koa-websocket) library, server instance of WebSocket is attached to `ctx` along side the request. That makes it really easy to manipulate the `wss.clients` Set (set of sessions in [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws)). For example pass parameters through URL and add it to Websocket instance something like this:

```
const wss = ctx.app.ws.server
const { userId } = ctx.request.query

try{

   ctx.websocket.uid = userId

}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
* on connect, server generate an unique id (e.g uuid) for the connection,
    * save it in memory, (e.g as key of map),
    * send back to client in response,
    * 
* 
* client save the id, on each request will also send the id as part of request data,
* then server identify the client by id, on receive further request,
* 
* server maintain client, e.g cleanup on close/error,
*
```

I've impl the idea, it works well to identify the client.
And, I also achieved group/topic broadcast based on the idea, which need the server to maintain extra info.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of interesting answers that do the job, however they mostly seem unclean, that is if you don't mind mutating the ws object. I did it this way because I'm using TypeScript and you can't arbitrarily add properties to objects.

```
import WebSocket from 'ws'

declare module 'ws' {
  interface WebSocket {
    id: any
    key: string
  }
}
```

The id doesn't have to be type any can be number or string depending on how you ID your connections. I haven't flushed out the system yet but for now when a connection is made, I just assign a random number.

```
const socketConnection = (socket: WebSocket.WebSocket): void => {
  socket.id = Math.random()
  console.log(socket.id)
  const msg = JSON.stringify({ res: `[open] Welcome to the WebSocket server!` })
  socket.send(msg)
}
```

This can be modified at any point so once I authenticate the connection I plan on assigning a relative ID here and might even add in a key property if I want to do some more fancy stuff.

How this works is explained in the Module Augmentation section of the documentation.

[TypeScript: Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

You can check that it's still assigned by looking over multiple messages in the onmessage event.

```
const socketMessage = (socket: WebSocket.WebSocket): void => {
  socket.on('message', async (message: WebSocket.RawData) => {
    console.log(socket.id)
    console.log(socket.key)
  })
}
```

Oh and a note, I made this module declaration in the document where I setup my socket. But the modification does populate across documents. For example in the AuthController I started prototyping I use it this way.

```
export default class AuthController {
  public static connections: DLinkedList = new DLinkedList()

  static async validate(request: { id: string, socket: WebSocket.WebSocket }): Promise<void> {
    console.log('test', request.socket.id)

    this.connections.add(request.socket, request.id)
    request.socket.send(JSON.stringify({ res: true }))
    console.log(this.connections.size())
  }

  static getSocket(id: string): WebSocket.WebSocket {
    return this.connections.getAtKey(id).data
  }

  static removeSocket(socket: WebSocket.WebSocket) {

  }
}
```

You can also do this in pure JS just by directly modifying the WebSocket object prototype. Some of the answers here talk about it. I haven't done it myself but the principle is similar.

[Add a method to an existing class in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999765/add-a-method-to-an-existing-class-in-typescript)

Hope this is useful.