# Ignore Typescript Errors "property does not exist on value of type"

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2013

In VS2013 building stops when tsc exits with code 1. This was not the case in VS2012.

How can I run my solution while ignoring the tsc.exe error?

I get many `The property 'x' does not exist on value of type 'y'` errors, which I want to ignore when using javascript functions.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

I know the question is already closed but I've found it searching for same TypeScriptException, maybe some one else hit this question searching for this problem.

 The problem lays in missing TypeScript typing:

```
var coordinates = outerElement[0].getBBox();
```

Throws `The property 'getBBox' does not exist on value of type 'HTMLElement'.`

The easiest way is to explicitly type variable as `any`

```
var outerHtmlElement: any = outerElement[0];
var coordinates = outerHtmlElement.getBBox();
```

#### Edit, late 2016

Since TypeScript 1.6, the prefered casting operator is `as`, so those lines can be squashed into:

`let coordinates = (outerElement[0] as any).getBBox();`

---

#### Other solutions

Of course if you'd like to do it right, which is an overkill sometimes, you can:

1. Create own interface which simply extends `HTMLElement`
2. Introduce own typing which extends `HTMLElement`

Comment: You could also create an interface that extends `HTMLElement` and has the additional `getBBox` property. That way you still get code completion on the other properties.

Comment: instead of casting into any to `getBBox` is there any method to cast propely ? like to find out the type of `getBBox` ?

Comment: F.E.: If `getBBox` would be in `HTMLElement` type you could cast the object to it by `var typedElement = <HTMLElement> outerHtmlElement;`.

Comment: nice!  `var coordinates = (<any>outerElement[0]).getBBox();`

Comment: "elegant" `(outerElement[0] as any).getBBox();` :D

Comment: This actually does not answer the question: "How to IGNORE the errors"

Comment: Please check `Other solutions` part to see actual elegant solutions :) PS  I don't think that there is an option to 'ignore' those compilation errors, it wouldn't make sense because it basically getting rid of static typing :) You can check available options for compilator setup: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html .

Comment: type any worked for me.  let newObj: any = {}; So When I create new porperties such as name, (e.g, newObj.name = this.nameInput;) I dont see any compilation errors anymore and was able to deploy to aws successfully.  THanks!

Comment: let coordinates = (outerElement[0] as any).getBBox(); for me.

Comment: Just a note, if you try to use optional chaining like ``obj.outerElement?[0].getBBox()`` this issue come back, pay attention to use `.` before the `?`

Comment: Explicitly casting it to type any (`myVariable as any`) solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 195):

The quick and dirty solution is to explicitly cast to `any`

```
(y as any).x
```

The "advantage" is that, the cast being explicit, this will compile even with the `noImplicitAny` flag set.

The proper solution is to update the typings definition file.

Please note that, when you cast a variable to `any`, you **opt out** of type checking for that variable.

---

Since I am in disclaimer mode, double casting via `any` combined with a new interface, can be useful in situations where

- you do not want to update a broken typings file
- and/or you are monkey patching

yet, you still want some form of typing.

Say you want to patch the definition of an instance of `y` of type `OrginalDef` with a new property `x` of type `number`:

```
const y: OriginalDef = ...

interface DefWithNewProperties extends OriginalDef {
    x: number
}

const patched = y as any as DefWithNewProperties

patched.x = ....   //will compile
```

Comment: thanks this helped: import http = require('http');
var server = http as any; server.Server(app); //ignores ts errors!

Comment: I used this in "ensure property not found on NodeRequire". so I declared my require variable on NodeRequired and (require as any).ensure for the property. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 84):

You can also use the following trick:

`y.x = "some custom property"//gives typescript error`

`y["x"] = "some custom property"//no errors`

Note, that to access `x` and dont get a typescript error again you need to write it like that `y["x"]`, not `y.x`. So from this perspective the other options are better.

Comment: Does anyone know why this works, and if this has any potential ramifications or benefits over initially declaring the object as `:any`?

Comment: It would have the clear benefit of keeping the typings, rather than casting to any.

I'd like to know why this doesn't throw a warning but accessing directly does..

Comment: seriously !?! this is so far beyond hackish... Yes it works because you are looking for the custom property using a string, but please don't. Renaming the property won't work with an IDE refactoring and it is mega error prone to use a hardcoded string.

Comment: @gotjosh suggest the alternative please.

Answer (score 42):

There are several ways to handle this problem. If this object is related to some external library, the best solution would be to find the actual definitions file (great repository [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)) for that library and reference it, e.g.:

```
/// <reference path="/path/to/jquery.d.ts" >
```

Of course, this doesn't apply in many cases.

If you want to 'override' the type system, try the following:

```
declare var y;
```

This will let you make any calls you want on `var y`.

Comment: Should be `/// <reference path="/path/to/jquery.d.ts" />` with the self closing tag at the end

Comment: I am using VS2015 and followed [this](https://softwarejuancarlos.com/2016/01/24/getting-started-with-asp-net-core-1-and-angular-2-in-visual-studio-2015/) tutorial for angular i don't have `jquery.d.ts` file in my project

Comment: @Dimple `npm install -g tsd` then `tsd install jquery`

Comment: The second option (declare var y) works great if you are migrating from JavaScript to TypeScript, and want to avoi error TS2304 because your old JavaScript is referencing a variable in another JavaScript file.

Comment: Thanks! For me the issue was with Jest, const mockPrompt: any = jest.spyOn(step, 'prompt');

Answer (score 29):

I know it's now 2020, but I couldn't see an answer that satisfied the "ignore" part of the question. Turns out, you can tell TSLint to do just that using a directive;

```
// @ts-ignore
this.x = this.x.filter(x => x.someProp !== false);
```

Normally this would throw an error, stating that 'someProp does not exist on type'. With the comment, that error goes away.

This will stop any errors being thrown when compiling and should also stop your IDE complaining at you.

Comment: Is there a tsconfig compilerOptions flag to completely disable this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. However, you can do it _per file_ by placing `@ts-nocheck` at the top of each file.

Comment: yeah, need better solution for that

Answer (score 27):

When TypeScript thinks that property **"x"** does not exist on **"y"**, then you can always cast "y" into "any", which will allow you to call anything (like "x") on "y".

**Theory**

```
(<any>y).x;
```

**Real World Example**

I was getting the error "TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Function'" for this code:

```
let name: string = this.constructor.name;
```

So I fixed it with:

```
let name: string = (<any>this).constructor.name;
```

Comment: Doesn't work with super.  If you extend a class using typings and author forgets a public method you're pretty much screwed.  You have to add it to the type definition, which gets stopped on the next npm install, forcing you to create a pull request or otherwise notify the author, which is probably a good thing but a pain.

Answer (score 17):

Had a problem in Angular2, I was using the local storage to save something and it would not let me.

Solutions:

I had `localStorage.city  -> error ->  Property 'city' does not exist on type 'Storage'.`

How to fix it:

> localStorage['city']
>
> (localStorage).city
>
> (localStorage as any).city

Comment: Second option looks cool, but doesn't seem to do the job anymore. Works if you prefix an object with `<any>` - `(<any>localStorage).city`.

Comment: I know this is old but your top example just worked for me..  Well done.

Answer (score 7):

A quick fix where nothing else works:

```
const a.b = 5 // error

const a['b'] = 5 // error if ts-lint rule no-string-literal is enabled

const B = 'b'
const a[B] = 5 // always works
```

Not good practice but provides a solution without needing to turn off no-string-literal

Comment: I do this too but some platforms (like Google Cloud) will raise a warning message suggesting that a.b is better than a['b']. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Not sure but you can, in tslint.json for example, change the options so that it prefers a.b

Answer (score 0):

In my particular project I couldn't get it to work, and used `declare var $;`. **Not a clean/recommended solution,** it doesnt recognise the JQuery variables, but I had no errors after using that (and had to for my automatic builds to succeed).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this in typescript using something like:

```
let x = [ //data inside array ];
let y = new Map<any, any>();
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    y.set(x[i], //value for this key here);
}
```

This seemed to be the only way that I could use the values inside X as keys for the map Y and compile.