# how to declare type of function property returned on object

Tags: typescript

When function `f` is called, it returns bar, so that I can then call `bar.baz()`. However, typescript complains that `Property baz does not exist on type (selection: any) => () => void` How can I declare the baz property of bar to make this compile?

```
   var f = function foo(){
        function bar(selection : any){
        }
        bar.baz = function(value){

        }
        return bar 
    }
```

(as an aside, I have this code inside an angular2 typescript project and it's very unforgiving. Other typescript projects I've worked on allow you to ignore the typescript errors, but this angular starter project really won't compile so I'm stuck until the typescript issue is resolved)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean this?

```
interface foo {
    (selection: any): void;
    baz: (value) => void;
}
var f = function () {
    var bar: foo = function (selection: any) {
    } as any
    bar.baz = function (value) {
    }
    return bar
}
```