# get indexedDb quota storage information

Tags: angular, typescript, indexeddb

I have tried below code to get indexedDb quota storage information

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
    console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
}, 
function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);
```

It is not working and giving the following error.

> Property 'webkitTemporaryStorage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

Can anyone provide solution for getting  indexedDb quota storage information in typescript?

Comment: Your code is working! I copied and pasted it into the browser console. What is the error message you get?

Comment: I am not getting.I used this code in typescript and getting error Property 'webkitTemporaryStorage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Comment: It is an issue related to typings in typeScript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lays in missing TypeScript typing. You can consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type/23553128#23553128).

To solve the issue, one solution is to declare the variable of type `any`:

```
let nav: any = navigator;
nav.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
    console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
}, 
function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);
```

Another way is to extend the interface of Navigator

```
interface Navigator {
    webkitTemporaryStorage: {
        queryUsageAndQuota ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Do not forget to upvote the answer :)

Comment: hi,I checked my indexeddb size in my appdata folder.it is 180kb only.But this code gives 761194596 bytes as used.Can you pls explain used bytes means for what

Comment: You can have a look at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem)