# Property 'share' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to use WebShareAPI in my Ionic application.

Here is my code as suggested in [Introducing the Web Share API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share)

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.share) {
  window.navigator.share({
    title: 'title',
    text: 'description',
    url: 'https://soch.in//',
  })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
} else {
  alert('share not supported');
}
```

However, Typescript compilation fails with the following error:

```
[11:31:11]  typescript: src/pages/channel_home/channel_home.ts, line: 89
            Property 'share' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
```

There is a likely reason explained here
[DOM lib: add support for navigator.share](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18642)

However, I would like to know some workaround to make WebShareApi work in my Ionic app in particular, and in any Angular or Typescript app in general.

Comment: This has been added to the global dom typings: https://github.com/microsoft/TSJS-lib-generator/pull/837 However, for me, in Angular 9.1 I still get the error, which is odd.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528131/get-indexeddb-quota-storage-information/47530085#47530085),
you can try to define a variable of type `any` and assign to it your value of Type Navigator. The issue is related to TypeScript typings.

```
const newVariable: any = window.navigator;

if (newVariable?.share) {
  newVariable.share({
    title: 'title',
    text: 'description',
    url: 'https://soch.in//',
  })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
} else {
  alert('Share is not supported');
}
```

Another option would be to extend the interface Navigator as it is suggested in the link I posted above.

Comment: Can't you simply use [globals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html) ?

Comment: @FlavienVolken, you mean adding a new interface type in a globals.d.ts file ? If the variable `navigator.share` is to be used at different level of the project, that will be a good choice, otherwise I will choose to proceed as I explain in the answer.

Comment: It's always better to place overriding properties on their own globals file (or typings.ts), because they are simply used to let typescript compiler work, not intended for real development, and when typings finally include the property you can easily find it and remove it

Comment: I like this solution but how would you handle the warning regarding the any type? ("Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type.")

Answer (score 14):

For anyone looking for a proper answer, just add this to your `global.d.ts` file:

```
type ShareData = {
    title? : string;
    text? : string;
    url? : string;
};

interface Navigator
{
    share? : (data? : ShareData) => Promise<void>;
}
```

This properly reflects the level 1 API.

Answer (score 13):

Declare `navigator` as `any`

```
(window.navigator as any).share
```

Comment: I like this solution but how would you handle the warning regarding the any type?     ("Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type.")

Answer (score 6):

### [Update 2020]

This is fixed in Typescript's latest versions (I am not exactly sure which one, but I guess since `v4.3-beta` version). Check this thread for details - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18642

Also,
The example shared below, once updated to the latest version will not work, as it conflicts with Typescript's own typings. Thus, do not apply those changes or keep the type similar to the parent:

```
// global.d.ts
interface Navigator extends Navigator {
  share: (options?: ShareData) => Promise<void>;
}
```

`share` property has been removed from being optional, as per the specs, details [implemented in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1573029), [changes in Firefox](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/edabd786a473#l3.14)

---

We can do this the `Typescript` way:

Firstly we need to define custom typings for our project. So, we need to define a `/typings` or `/@types` folder in your root directory.

```sh
.
└── typings
```

Once that is done, you need to update your `tsconfig.json` file to point the new custom typings folder to this one.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./typings"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    ...
    "typings",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
  ...
}
```

This will allow Typescript to look for custom types in `/typings` folder.

References for above:

- [Angular University Typescript Typings](https://blog.angular-university.io/typescript-2-type-system-how-do-type-definitions-work-in-npm-when-to-use-types-and-why-what-are-compiler-opt-in-types/)
- [Typescript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)

Once the above is done, we need to create a Global `.d.ts` file that Typescript will look into for detecting custom types. So, in your `/typings` folder create a new file named `global.d.ts`.

```
// global.d.ts
interface Navigator extends Navigator {
  share?: (options: any) => Promise<void>;
}
```

*What we are doing, is overriding the default `Navigator` with some extra properties to support.*

Once you declare the above interface, Typescript will allow you to use `navigator.share`, but you need to put it inside a conditional block, as `share` is optional property, it might or might not be present in a Browser.

- [Typescript Docs on Global Definitions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 5):

This also works and we don't need to create a newVariable.

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.share) {
  window.navigator['share']({
    title: 'title',
    text: 'description',
    url: 'https://soch.in//',
  })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
} else {
  alert('share not supported');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case: in Angular, on a module I use:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
```

and typescript show the error MozGetUserMedia is not a property.

I fixed using:

```
declare const navigator: any;
```

Maybe the same approach will works for you:

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
let newVariable = (window.navigator as any)
if(newVariable.share){
  newVariable.share({
  title: 'title',
  text: 'description',
  url: 'https://soch.in//',
})
  .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
  .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
} else {
  alert('share not supported');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use navigator.share/caches/serial and many more directly, this will lead you to an error on the HTTP connection.
Verify it exists before the direct call to the property.

```
if ('share' in navigator) {
//Do stuff
} else {
 alert('Share API not supported');
}
```

Comment: `if ('share' in navigator) {` did the trick in my case...

Answer (score 0):

If you keep getting the error, despite following the advices on this site, make sure that your page is server via `https`. The share functionality is not available on plain http. The following snipped worked for me.

```js
const nav: any = window.navigator;
nav.share({ title: "Shared via my https page", url: "relativeLink" })
```