# How to use navigator and location DOM variables in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom, types

so I'm doing a project that uses react and typescript, however I need to access some DOM variables like navigator and location. However I can access those vars in a JS file but not is TS file. I've been searching but couldn't find any answer. I hope this is not trivial.

Example of a function I called in JS but need it to be in TS:

```
const { usage, quota } = await navigator.storage.estimate();
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: **See Also**: [Property 'share' does not exist on type 'Navigator'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47831741/1366033)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add option to your **tsconfig.json** file.

Add **dom** to **compilerOptions.lib** array like here:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom"
        ]
  }
}
```

This option will add necessary typings for DOM API.

Comment: Thank you so much it did the job!