# How to fix Property 'permissions' does not exist on type 'Navigator'?

Tags: angular, typescript, browser

While the permissions API was in draft form for a while, it seems to be well supported now. But typescript still gives the  `Property 'permissions' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.` error for code like:

```
if (navigator.permissions) { 
    /* code */
}
```

or

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'})
    .then((result) => {
        /* code */
    })
```

How to handle this in an Angular 7+ application?

This is my current `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the target of your TS config? I tried in TS playground, TS can recognize permissions

Comment: Please show your tsconfig.json. You might need to add something to [`lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib).

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: **See Also**: [Property 'share' does not exist on type 'Navigator'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47831741/1366033)

Comment: It is similar to that question, but this is different because of the changing status of the permissions API for different browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simplest answer is to use `declare`**

It's possible to write custom type declarations for your application, but since this is a global, browser variable, and not going to be part of your application's code, a simpler path is likely more sustainable and comprehensible to other engineers on your team.  By utilizing the Typescript `declare` keyword, you can notify the compiler that you are using an existing variable, object, or library and are specifying its type.

So for an Angular component, the `declare` keyword can be used to tell Typescript that properties on a global variable (like `navigator`) are ok:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...

declare const navigator: any;  // This is the declaration you add

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css'],
})
...

if (navigator.permissions) {   // Typescript is happy now
  ...
}
```

More information:

- [Typescript Docs: Working with Other JavaScript Libraries](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries)
- [Purpose of declare keyword in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript)

Comment: Next level Answer buddy... thank you so much