# Why Does Declaring Type <any> Resolve Error with Unknown Method? (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I had this code:

`this.$(<string> button.className + ' input').bootstrapToggle('on');`

Typescript gave me this error:

`error TS2339: Property 'bootstrapToggle' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.`

I successfully fixed the error with this:

`(<any> this.$(<string> button.className + ' input')).bootstrapToggle('on');`

Why does declaring the element to be of 'any' type resolve this error?

Comment: You can consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `bootstrapToggle` is not defined on the declaration file of jquery.

Try and add this definition by adding the declaration of this type under a `.d.ts` file in your project

```
interface BootstrapToggleOptions {
    on?: string;

    off?: string;

    onstyle?: OnOffStyle;

    offstyle?: OnOffStyle;

    size?: Size;

    width?: number;

    height?: number;
}

type OnOffStyle = "default" | "primary" | "success" | "info" | "warning" | "danger";
type Size = "large" | "normal" | "small" | "mini";

interface JQuery {
    bootstrapToggle(): JQuery;

    bootstrapToggle(options?: BootstrapToggleOptions): JQuery;
}
```

Using the `(<any> this.$(<string> button.className + ' input'))` hack, is not advisable it sort of defeats the point of typing.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful!