# Get plotly bar chart data on click in Angular app

Tags: angular, onclick, plotly

I added a plotly component to my project following [this guide](https://damienbod.com/2016/04/21/creating-an-angular-2-component-for-plotly/). When the user clicks on the bar chart, I need to get the data corresponding to the bar that the user clicked on. The structure is just like in [the guide](https://damienbod.com/2016/04/21/creating-an-angular-2-component-for-plotly/) I followed and everything works great, I just do not know how to add a click event to the bar chart.
The bar chart looks like this
[image]
When the user clicks the chart, I need to get the associated vehicle make, like "HUMMER" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `Plotly.newPlot`, you can add a click event handler and access the clicked data like this

```js
(document.getElementById('myPlotlyDiv') as any).on('plotly_click', function(data){
    // The label of the horizontal bar chart
    console.log(data.points[0].y);
    // The value for the clicked bar
    console.log(data.points[0].x);
});
```

Comment: Updated answer to ignore the typescript error `Property 'on' does not exist on type "'myPlotlyDiv'"`, which I found at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type)

Answer (score 0):

The guide uses `any` type. However, your ESLint setup might give you some errors later on:

```
@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access: Unsafe member access .on on an `any` value.
@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call: Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.
```

Our days Plotly.js is definitely typed. So, you need to install as a developer dependence some types for plotly.js (e.g. `npm i -D @types/plotly.js-dist-min`) and use them:

```js
import { PlotlyHTMLElement } from 'plotly.js-dist-min';
const myPlot = document.getElementById('myPlotlyDiv') as PlotlyHTMLElement;
myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
    // The label of the horizontal bar chart
    console.log(data.points[0].y);
    // The value for the clicked bar
    console.log(data.points[0].x);
    });
});
```