# Iterate through a prop, but sort by a different prop React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, sorting

I have this function that sorts the array by the Defect(string), however, I want to iterate through the Count(number).

```
getCount() {

let arr = this.state.rows
  let arr2 = arr.filter(qc => qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.length > 0).map((qc) =>
      qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.map((qc2) =>
          qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) => qc3).sort((a, b) 
              => a.Defect < b.Defect ? -1 : a.Defect > b.Defect ? 1: 0)));

        return arr2
    };
```

This function returns

```
0: {BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsID: "-LbiHz7tuuJH71I_4IKw", Defect: "Bruise", Count: 2, BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs: null}
1: {BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsID: "-LbiHz7tuuJH71I_4IKw", Defect: "Hail damage", Count: 0, BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs: null}
2: {BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsID: "-LbiHz7tuuJH71I_4IKw", Defect: "Scuff", Count: 2, BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs: null}
3: {BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsID: "-LbiHz7tuuJH71I_4IKw", Defect: "Sunburn", Count: 1, BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs: null}
```

My array is sorted, however inside my original function I would like to iterate over Count, not the whole object.

It would look like something like this..

```
 qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) => qc3.Count).sort((a, b) 
               => a.Defect < b.Defect ? -1 : a.Defect > b.Defect ? 1: 0)));
```

But I'm currently getting "property 'Defect' does not exist on type 'number'

It should also be noted that I'm using TypeScript with React

my interface
`BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs: { BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects: { Defect: string, Count: number }[] }[]`

Comment: What do you expect your `getCount` function to return _**after**_ you make the changes that you're planning?

Comment: I would like it to return Count, but sorted by Defect

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is because when you use map it will essentially output an array that only contains the values of count

```
qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) => qc3.Count)
```

Outputs:

```
[2, 0, 2 , 1]
```

You should first sort and then map, try it the other way:

```
qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.sort((a, b) => a.Defect < b.Defect ? -1 : a.Defect > b.Defect ? 1: 0))).map((qc3) => qc3.Count);
```

Also, here you are sorting strings so I am not sure if that'll work properly but at least you should not get the error about the property not existing.

UPDATE:

I had missed in your post that you are using Typescript, try this to see if it works as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type)

```
qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.sort((a, b) => a.Defect < b.Defect ? -1 : a.Defect > b.Defect ? 1: 0))).map((qc3) => (qc3 as any).Count);
```

Another suggestion would be to try with `qc3["Count"]` instead of `qc3.Count`, Typescript somehow does not perceive this thing equally...

Comment: what output do you get when you run this `qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.sort((a, b) => a.Defect < b.Defect ? -1 : a.Defect > b.Defect ? 1: 0)))`

Comment: The same output in my OP

Comment: Help me understand something why are you returning arr2 when you are defining arr2?

Comment: Also how about you create a fiddleJS it'll be easier to help you debug

Comment: Well if I don't return arr2 then It's undefined...won't be able to use jsFiddle..I'm retrieving the data from a local DB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192604/discussion-between-tekill-and-invrt).

Comment: actually test .map((qc3) => qc3["Count"])