# Why I'm getting property does not exist on type object error here?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm attempting to narrow down and identify an unknown object with this function.

```js
// typescript
function checkObject(bar: unknown) {
  // bar: unknown
  if (typeof bar !== "object") {
    // proceed only if it is object
    return;
  }

  // bar: object | null
  // eliminate null
  if (!bar) {
    return;
  }

  // check if there is a property "par" in the object
  if (bar.par) { // => TS Error: Property 'par' does not exist on type 'object'.(2339)
    // ... 
  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawPICMBWGUAFLgIYBOAXIuJmHAO5gCUiA3gLABQiiMwRMSgBPAA5o4g8hUQBCALwLEAIjgEiKtl159EAen2IxFOBDRoAJogQAbEf0Ewo-AM42N0HnsQU0UEAowAG5vRABfHjDDRDRbGABbGDAyKDREMBBbWwAaIVEJKQys20QlZQBydUJoCpYwgSE5GW0wvj8AoNDdSO4GwVJKADoxSm0DIwUAPkQAUQpTakQABVMJClFECtGKCsRLODR3Bhc0AA8YVxcERAL0qs8oCqHiACYAZneATnrdPhihoDEGFer0gA)

Why am I getting this error after all these checks?

*(I know there are workarounds like `(bar as any).par`. But I'm interested in knowing why the compiler not picking these checks up)*

Comment: May be you will get your answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type?rq=1

Comment: "bar" variable is still "unknown" type, so you can not access any properties. Even if you cast it to "object" you will not have access to properties. You have to cast to more specific type. At least you can use "bar as {par:string}".