# Property does not exist on type 'object' from third party function

Tags: typescript

I have a 3rd party function (someone else's library) that is returning an object via a Promise. I'd like to do this:

```
externalClient
 .query("...")
 .then((value) => value.data);
```

Just to be clear, `externalClient.query` is a function I didn't write.

However, typescript is erroring with the message `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'object'. ts(2339)`

How do I handle this?

Comment: Can you log the object? If so, what does it show?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore Typescript Errors "property does not exist on value of type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type)

Comment: You can give your expected type like this `.then((value: MyTypeDef) => value.data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @Akhil:

You can give your expected type like this `.then((value: MyTypeDef) => value.data);`