# express in TypeScript middleware method can't match overload with callback

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm making a listener to listen from Webhook:

```
import express, {Express, NextFunction, Request, Response} from "express";
import config from '../config.json' assert {type: "json"};

const listener = express();

interface LangInReq extends Request {
    recvTime: number;
}

listener.use('/recv', (req: LangInReq, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
/* 
src/server.ts:10:23 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: LangInReq, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: LangInReq, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => void' is missing the following properties from type 'Application<Record<string, any>>': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 63 more.

10 listener.use('/recv', (req: LangInReq, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:185:5
    185     (path: PathParams, subApplication: Application): T;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The last overload is declared here.
*/
    req.recvTime = Date.now();
    
    let token = req.get('x-telegram-bot-api-secret-token');
    if(token !== config.telegram.botToken) {
        console.log(`[WARN] Unauthorized request from ${req.ip} with token ${token}`);
        return;
    }

    next();
})

listener.use(express.json());

listener.use('/recv', (req: LangInReq) => {
    
})
```

[code with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzmqo.png)
this problem shows once the parameter of callback is more than one. Would someone tell me how to solve this and hint me with index.d.ts?

- I have imported Request, Response, NextFunction, which is shown in image.

```
package.json

"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^18.2.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^20.5.9",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
```

```
tsconfig.json

"extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES2020",
  "module": "NodeNext",
  "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
}
```

I started with (req: Request) with no problem, then I added next: NextFunction and it popped up. same problem for (req, res, next) (with type), only (next) and only (req) are pass.
currently I just need (req, next) for I'm listening webhook here.

**[Update]** I've found `(req, res, next)` without type annotation can pass. This means problem should comes from `interface LangInReq`, I'll put a link here and checkout myself later for I'm busy now. [Accessing middleware injected data in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243903/accessing-middleware-injected-data-in-typescript)