# Websockets: send messages and notifications to all clients except sender

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, webrtc

I am developing chat based on websockets and webrtc. I would like to send messages to all connected users except sender but I cannot find suitable solution. To be more specific, I would like to send notifications to other  connected users that new user has joined to the chat.
I am trying to give a unique ID to every connected user, but the first assigned ID is re-writed by every new user and I cannot diferentiate users.

Server:

```
// list of users
var CLIENTS=[];
var id;

// web server is using 8081 port
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({ port: 8081 });

// check if connection is established
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

id = Math.random();
CLIENTS[id] = ws;
CLIENTS.push(ws);

ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
    var received = JSON.parse(message);

    if(received.type == "login"){
        ws.send(message);  // send message to itself

        /* *********************************************************** */
        /* *** Here I trying to check if message comes from sender *** */

        sendNotes(JSON.stringify({
            user: received.name,
            type: "notes"
        }), ws, id);

        /* *********************************************************** */
    }else if(received.type == "message"){
        sendAll(message); // broadcast messages to everyone including sender
    }

});

ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('user ' + CLIENTS[ws] + ' left chat');
    delete CLIENTS[ws];
});

});

function sendNotes(message, ws, id) {
    console.log('sendNotes : ', id);
    if (CLIENTS[id] !== ws) {
        console.log('IF : ', message);
        for (var i = 0; i < CLIENTS.length; i++) {
            CLIENTS[i].send(message);
        }
    }else{
        console.log('ELSE : ', message);
    }
}

   function sendAll(message) {
       for (var i=0; i < CLIENTS.length; i++) {
          CLIENTS[i].send(message); // broadcast messages to everyone including sender
       }
   }
```

Client:

```
loginButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    name = usernameInput.value;

    if(name.length > 0){
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({
            type: "login",
            name: name
        }));
    }

});

function sendData() {
    var data = dataChannelSend.value;
    var userName = document.getElementById('greetingUser').innerHTML;

    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        username : userName,  // fetch user name from browser, after login
        type : "message",
        message : data
    }));
}

socket.onmessage = function(message) {

    var envelope = JSON.parse(message.data);
    switch(envelope.type) {
        case "login":
            onLogin(envelope);
            break;
        case "message":
            showMessage(envelope);
            break;
    }
};
```

I would highly appreciate If you could give me any hint. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Here is a very simple way of sending to everyone connected except the sender.

Create a broadcast function on your webSocketServer instance that will
take two params.

```
...
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({ port: 8081 });
...
/*
 * method: broadcast
 * @data: the data you wanna send
 * @sender: which client/ws/socket is sending
 */
webSocketServer.broadcast = function(data, sender) {
  webSocketServer.clients.forEach(function(client) {
    if (client !== sender) {
      client.send(data)
    }
  })
}

...
// On your message callback.
ws.on('message', function(message) {
 ...
  // Note that we're passing the (ws) here
  webSocketServer.broadcast(message, ws);
})
```

That's it, the broadcast method will send to each connected client
except the one who is sending.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so we are now storing the CLIENTS in a way that allows us to uniquely identify each client that is connecting, and store arbitrary information about them for later retrieval.

The code below will send the "notes" message to all clients, and THEN add the newly connecting client to the "all clients" list.

SERVER.JS:

```
var http = require('http'),
    Static = require('node-static'),
    WebSocketServer = new require('ws'),

    // list of users
    /*
        We are now storing client data like this:

        CLIENTS = {

            uniqueRandomClientID: {

                socket: {},         // The socket that this client is connected on
                clientDetails: {    // Any details you might wish to store about this client

                    username: "",
                    etc: "etc"
                }
            }
        };

        So now to get at the socket for a client, it'll be: CLIENTS[uniqueRandomClientID].socket.
        Or to show a client's username, it'll be: CLIENTS[uniqueRandomClientID].clientDetails.username.
        You might want to write a 'getClientByUsername' function that iterates the CLIENTS array and returns the client with that username.
    */
    CLIENTS = {},

    // web server is using 8081 port
    webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({ port: 8081 });

// check if connection is established
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

    console.log('connection is established');

    // Now using a randomly generated ID to reference a client. Probably should be better than Math.random :D
    var wsID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

    ws.on('message', function(message) {

        console.log('received: %s', message);
        var received = JSON.parse(message);

        if(received.type == "login"){

            // If a client with this login name doesnt exist already, its a new client
            if(!CLIENTS[wsID]) {

                doBroadcast(
                    {
                        "newuser": received.name,
                        type: "notes"
                    }
                );

                // Now add this new client to the list
                CLIENTS[wsID] = {

                    socket: ws,
                    clientDetails: {

                        username: received.name
                    }
                };
            }
        } else if(received.type == "message") {

            doBroadcast(message); // broadcast messages to everyone including sender
        }
    });

    ws.on('close', function(_event) {

        if(CLIENTS[wsID]) {

            console.log('user ' + CLIENTS[wsID].clientDetails.username + ' left chat');
            delete CLIENTS[wsID];
        }
    });

    /*
    * Added this to 'catch' errors rather than just red dump to console. I've never actually done anything with this myself (I *like* red text in my console), but I know this handler should be here :P
    */
    ws.on('error', function(_error) {

        console.log("error!");
        console.log(_error);
    });

    /*
    * Send an object to a client
    *
    * @param WebSocketClient _to - The client you want to send to (generally an index in the CLIENTS array, i.e CLIENTS["bobsusername123"]
    * @param Object _message - A stringifyable JSON object. Complex ones can screw things up, but your basic key/value pairs are usually fine to send.
    */
    function doSend(_to, _message) {

        _to.send(JSON.stringify(_message));
    };

    // Added broadcast function to replace sendAll
    // Notice how it JSON stringifies the data before sending
    /*
    * Broadcast a message to all clients
    *
    * @param Object _message - A stringifyable JSON object. Complex ones can screw things up, but your basic key/value pairs are usually fine to send.
    */
    function doBroadcast(_message) {

        for(var client in CLIENTS) {

            if(!CLIENTS.hasOwnProperty(client)) continue;

            doSend(CLIENTS[client].socket, _message);
        }
    };
});

var fileServer = new Static.Server('.');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    fileServer.server(req, res);

}).listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Server is listening 8080 port.");
});

console.log("Server is running on 8080 and 8081 ports");
```

MY CLIENT.JS (for your reference):

```
var loginButton = document.getElementById("loginbutton"),
    usernameInput = document.getElementById("usernameInput");

var SocketClient = function(_uri, _callbacks) {

    this.uri = _uri;
    this.callbacks = _callbacks;
};

SocketClient.prototype = {

    send: function(_message) {

        this.socket.send(_message);
    },

    connect: function() {

        try {

            this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + this.uri);
        } catch(e) { return false; }

        for(var callback in this.callbacks) {

            if(!this.callbacks.hasOwnProperty(callback)) continue;
            this.socket["on" + callback] = this.callbacks[callback];
        }

        return true;
    }
};

var socketClient = new SocketClient(

    "127.0.0.1:8081",
    {
        open: function() {

            console.log("connected.");
        },
        message: function(_message) {

            console.log("received data:");
            console.log(_message);
        },
        close: function() {

            console.log("closed.");
        },
        error: function(_error) {

            console.log("error: ");
            console.log(_error);
        }
    }
);

socketClient.connect();

loginButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

    name = usernameInput.value;

    if(name.length > 0){

        socketClient.send(JSON.stringify({
            type: "login",
            name: name
        }));
    }

});
```

AND THE CLIENT.HTML TO GO WITH IT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="usernameInput"/>
        <button type="button" id="loginbutton">Login</button>
        <script src="client.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ive tested this with NWJS v0.12.3 running the server and Firefox on the client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check your answer soon

Comment: Did you update all your references to CLIENTS, bearing in mind with my changes it is now accessed with the syntax CLIENTS[string clientLoginName]. If you can show me your updated code and a screen print of your errors as you did before, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I just noticed I spelled recieved wrong in my code. Sorry about that, ill update it now. Hopefully you noticed & fixed it in your code already :D

Comment: sure, no worries :) I just put code in plunker, you can check it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/iVWuGqUduJbJnzVuzGLC?p=catalogue the files are server.js and client.js

Comment: do you have the full client.js code (i.e the bits that define socket etc)? Ive set up this project on my PC  and have the server running. Just need a client to connect to it so i can test.

Comment: sure, but it contains webrtc code as well, I will mark websocket's code so it will be easy for you to read.

Comment: ah webrtc. no worries, ive knocked up my own ws client and have it connected now. im getting the same error. ill update my answer when i find the issue.

Comment: You can download code here, client part is in `basic/js/main.js` and server part `basic/js/server.js`, please let me know if you have any questions: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4r0i21mntjeszwd/AADR0KF3pljh2HmQ1d590a_Ka?dl=0

Comment: could you specify them?

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan Your fileServer.server call is not working for me, it says object has no method server. You should use express, it is easy and always works. Here is an example:
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io');
server.listen(8000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8000');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/') );

Comment: Thanks @droid-zilla but it is not the full code of a server. You can find full code here: https://gist.github.com/johannesMatevosyan/5ec0f7139c1804cc3bbb

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

// Websocket variables
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    port: 3000
});
console.log('Websocket active on port 3000...');


// New WebSocket Connection
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

    console.log('new connection')

    // On Message Received
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {

        console.log(message)
        
        // Send To Everyone Except Sender
        wss.clients.forEach(function(client) {
            if (client !== ws) client.send(message);
        });

    });


});
```