# Add a method to an existing class in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working in an angular 2 cli project in which I have to create a definition of a plugin, because it doesn't exists its typed. This plugin depends of a main library that has already its own typed and it works.

Anyway,
I have two files
the main one with

LIBRARY TYPES FILE A

```
export class A extends B {
    constructor(...);
    methodX(): void;
}
```

And I would need to add a new method for my plugin so my class would be like

```
export class A extends B {
        constructor(...);
        methodX(): void;
        methodY(): void;
    }
```

The point is that I need to add it in a separate file. The problem is adding a method to an existent class without creating a new one

If I put

PLUGIN TYPES FILE B

```
export class A extends B {
    constructor(...);
    methodX(): void;
}
```

or

PLUGIN TYPES FILE B

```
export class A extends B {
        constructor(...);
        methodX(): void;
        methodY(): void;
}
```

It doesn't work, does anyone how can I achieve overwriting a class or extending it with a new method that?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure from your question. It is not clear. Do you need Mixins? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Comment: If you ask how "extending it", it is simple as `class C extends A`. But I think you mean "adding a new method without changing the class name". If that is right, please clarify your question.

Comment: also, why not just extend the class and add the method?

Comment: @toskv because sometimes you want to extend capabilities of a commonly used class. For example, adding `flatMap` to `Array` if you're using NodeJS < 11 (`ts-node` is Node in version 8).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do it by making an interface with the new method and modifying the prototype.

Something like this:

```js
class B { }

class A extends B {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    methodX(): void { };
    methodY(): void { };
}


interface B {
    newMethod(): void;
}

B.prototype.newMethod = function () { console.log('a') };
```

This allows you do have proper typing when doing.

```
new A().newMethod();
```

I made a playground example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20B%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20methodX()%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20methodY()%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20newMethod()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AB.prototype.newMethod%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20console.log('a')%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20A().newMethod()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A).

Comment: Do you need to use an interface? I added the function to the class itself, and it worked.

Comment: I had to add it otherwise the interface of B doesn't change and it wouldn't let me change the prototype of B.

Comment: it might depend where you make the change. in your example you do it inside the class itself. I do it from the outside. I think the OP wasn't allowed to change the code. :)

Comment: nope, it's not that.. I think it's just plnkr not complaining about it. :) It might have something to do with in browser compiler.

Comment: I didn't think he was asking to change interface B, but it makes sense to do it this way. My answer becomes unnecessary then, sorry for duplicate answer :)

Comment: well.. I agree he wasn't explicitly asking for it but it is implicit, if you change the class, you change it's type as well. Luckily with typescript's open interfaces it's easy to do it. :)

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül as for your answer, it's a good answer well written too. :)

Comment: Awesome!!!!Thx it works perfectly. I am working with leaflet and plugins and I was able to integrate through the interface without modifying the main class

Comment: This thing has a problem. Typescript thinks that the new property is own to the object, and don't know that it is from the prototype. This may cause problems when you copy the object with the spread operator.

Comment: In general mixing class instances and the spread operator will lead to issues. If you plan on making copies of class instances you're probably better off using a clone method or a copy constructor.

Answer (score 27):

The "Declaration Merging > Module Augmentation" section from the TypeScript docs seems to offer the solution:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

In your case, if `class A` is exported from `file1.ts`, and you want to add `methodY()` to that class within a different module `file2.ts`, then try this:

```
//// file1.ts
export class A extends B {
    constructor(...);
    methodX(): void;
}

//// file2.ts
import { A } from "./file1";
declare module "./file1" {
    interface A {
        methodY(): void;
    }
}
A.prototype.methodY = function() {}
```

Comment: Btw adding a new method to a class within the SAME file would have been done like so:

`class A {};
interface A {
    methodY(): void;
};
A.prototype.methodY = function () {};`

Comment: This is the one solution that actually worked! Thanks!

Comment: to add to the first comment, `declare module './file1'` still works inside of `file1.ts` You must do this for the compiler to understand your calls to `methodY` in other places. Read more here on [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it directly as `A.prototype.functionName = function(){...}`

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6KrhTCLTHw9wjMTSI7NH?p=preview

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I've found in VSCode with typescript it won't accept the 'A.prototype.functionName' notation but will accept 'A.prototype["functionName"]'.