# Adding methods to external class via module augmentation : error

Tags: typescript

This seems so trivial, yet I fail to make it work.
I have a class `Collection` in an external npm dependency (say `packagename`). In my current project, I would like to add some methods to the prototype of that class, and informing TS of that fact.

In the external module, the class is defined like :

```js
export class Collection<T extends Document> {
  // ...
}
```

So here is what I wrote in an `external.d.ts` file in my project :

```js
import { Document } from "packagename";

declare module "packagename" {
  export interface Collection<T extends Document> {
    newMethod(): Promise<T | null>;
  }
}
```

But then in another file :

```js
import { Collection } from "packagename"

Collection.prototype.newMethod= function<T extends Document>(this: Collection<T>) {
  // ...
};
```

fails with the following error :

```
TS2693: 'Collection' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Same goes if I import `Collection` with `import * as everything from 'packagename'` then `everything.Collection`.

What am I missing here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that it doesn't work because imports from `packagename` are re-exported imports in a `index.ts` file that only aggregates other files. Targeting the exact source file of the class I wanted to augment seems to work :

```js
import { Document } from "packagename";

declare module "packagename/dist/collection" {
  export interface Collection<T extends Document> {
    newMethod(): Promise<T | null>;
  }
}
```

[This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11406#issuecomment-251826043) gave me the hint.

Answer (score 0):

1. Typescript allows you to extend the interface (what you did), but the interface is just a type (no implementation as you see).
2. I do not understand you need to extend the class in that way. Why don't you just create a child class based on the existing one? It seems like a right way to extend class instead of monkey patching via prototype extending

```
import { Collection } from "packagename"

export class ExtendedCollection extends Collection {
  newMethod() {

  }
}
```

and after that in places, you need just import and use that new class

do you have strong reasons to not do it in such a way?

Comment: Because then I wouldn't be able to use `newMethod` for example on a `Collection` returned by the external package (which is a type that I don't control). Module augmentation is supposed to work around that. Example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61485387/11153160