# TypeScript/JavaScript terser mix-ins

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic, subclass, mixins

There is an article on using and creating mix-ins on MDN
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends#mix-ins). I've tried to implement this in TypeScript:

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any) => any;

function nameMixin(Base: Constructor) {
  return class extends Base {
    #name?: string;

    name() {
      return this.#name;
    }

    setName(name: string) {
      this.#name = name;
    }
  };
}

class None {}
class Foo extends nameMixin(None) {
  constructor(private value: number) {
    super();
  }
}

const foo = new Foo(10)
foo.setName("john")
foo.name()
```

This seems to work pretty well but the one thing I don't particularly like about this trick is that I have to extend the arbitrary `None` class.

I've seen other people implement mix-ins with `Object.assign(Foo.prototype, mixin)`, where `mixin` is an object, but I don't like that because it decouples the mix-in from the declaration.

Anyone know any other, cleaner ways of implementing mix-ins?

Comment: Mixins are very well-covered in the [official typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html)...

Comment: 1/2 ... And yet, a function which accepts a class-reference as its sole parameter and does create and return another class which extends the passed super-class should never be allowed to be called a mixin (related) technique. **The function is a factory which dynamically creates a subclass. Thus it relies on inheritance; and the latter is diametral to composition.** On the other hand, amongst other techniques/patterns, real mixins do cover composition. Every usage of the above identified factory should be called what it actually is, _**dynamic subclassing**_ or _**dynamic sub-typing**_.

Comment: 2/2 ... And applying the factory pattern e.g. like this ... [`class Router extends asEventTargetProxy(UniversalRouter) { /* ... */ }`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77553408/2627243) where `asEventTargetProxy` with every invocation creates another version of an `EventTargetProxy` subclass should be called _**Interpositioned Dynamic Subclassing**_.

Comment: @AdamB ... 1/2 ... Have a look into [this answer of _**"How can I 'augment' a JS class with methods from another class, without extending it?"**_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77530026/2627243) because the OP's matter gets examined from both sides, real composition achieved by function based mixins and inheritance driven by dynamic subclassing.

Comment: @AdamB ... 2/2 ... In case of being in need of diving deeper into this on the basis of a more complex use case, have a look into both answers of [_**"How to implement Web-API EventTarget functionality into a class which already extends another class?"**_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611255/how-to-implement-web-api-eventtarget-functionality-into-a-class-which-already-ex).

Comment: Sorry that I haven't been following this thread, I've been digging around & eventually found the most appealing way of doing this for me via interface declaration merging + adding to prototype (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999765/add-a-method-to-an-existing-class-in-typescript). Thanks for all your help however, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @AdamB. ... Thanks for coming back and leaving the note/link about which solution finally could help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Anyone know any other, cleaner ways of implementing mix-ins?"*

The, in my opinion, still most versatile pattern of the many different ways of accomplishing mixins in JavaScript is a ***function based mixin*** which is ***aware of a `this` context***, thus it always gets applied via `call` to the object in need of a mixed-in behavior.

In addition of always working upon a delegated/bound `this`, one, at apply time, can either pass variables like string and number values or even object-references which could be used as privately shared (even mutable) state amongst other such alike implemented mixins and the classes/factories which do create objects with mixed-in behavior.

```js
// `this` context aware function based mixin.
function withSetGetName(name = '') {

  // delegated/bound `this` context.
  Reflect.defineProperty(this, 'name', {

    // returning the locally scoped variable.
    get: () => name,

    // - controlling whether and how to change the
    //   locally scoped (private) variable's value.
    set: (value) => (name = value),
  });
  return this;
}

class Foo {
  #number;

  constructor(name, number) {
    this.#number = number;

    // applying the function based mixin.
    withSetGetName.call(this, name);
  }
}

// instance of class which does mixin-in.
const foo = new Foo('Jim', 10);

// a plain object with mixed-in behavior.
const bar = withSetGetName.call({});

console.log(
  'foo.name =>', foo.name
);
console.log(
  "foo.name = 'John' =>", (foo.name = 'John')
);
console.log(
  'foo.name =>', foo.name
);

console.log(
  'bar.name =>', bar.name
);
console.log(
  "bar.name = 'Jane' =>", (bar.name = 'Jane')
);
console.log(
  'bar.name =>', bar.name
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```