# how do i send a message to a specific user in ws library?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm exploring different websocket library for self-learning and I found that this library is really amazing [ws-node](https://github.com/websockets/ws). I'm building a basic 1 on 1 chat in ws-node library

My question is what is the equivalent of `socket.io` function which is `socket.to().emit()` in ws? because i want to send a message to a specific user.

Frontend - socket.io

```
socket.emit("message", { message: "my name is dragon", userID: "123"});
```

Serverside - socket.io

```
// listening on Message sent by users
socket.on("message", (data) => {
    // Send to a specific user for 1 on 1 chat
    socket.to(data.userID).emit(data.message);
});
```

WS - backend

```
const express = require('express');
const http =  require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const express = require('express');
const http =  require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {

    ws.on('message', (data) => {   
        \\ I can't give it a extra parameter so that I can listen on the client side, and how do I send to a specific user?
        ws.send(`Hello, you sent -> ${data.message}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you realize that you can't connect a socket.io front-end to a webSocket back-end?  You must connect socket.io client ==> socket.io server or webSocket client ==> webSocket server.

Comment: webSocket by itself does not have a message emitting system like socket.io does.  That's one of the features that socket.io adds on top of webSocket.  You send packets with webSocket and the data format in those packets is up to you.  You could put a message name in every packet and then invent a system for listening to specific message events or just use socket.io to get that feature and many others.

Comment: see great answer from @Jzapata: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878342/10861398

Comment: @airsoftFreak Hi I have the same problem with you.. have you found the solution of your question?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an equivalent method. `socket.io` comes with a lot of helpers and functionalities, that will make your life easier, such as rooms, events...

`socket.io` is a realtime application framework, while `ws` is just a WebSocket client.

---

You will need to make your custom wrapper:

```
const sockets = {};

function to(user, data) {

    if(sockets[user] && sockets[user].readyState === WebSocket.OPEN)
        sockets[user].send(data);
}

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {

    const userId = getUserIdSomehow(ws);
    sockets[userId] = ws;

    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        // Or get user in here
    });

    ws.on('close', function incoming(message) {
        delete sockets[userId];
    });

});
```

And then use it like this:

```
to('userId', 'some data');
```

In my opinion, if you seek that functionality, you should use `socket.io`. Which it's easy to integrate, has a lot of support, and have client libraries for multiple languages.

If your front-end uses `socket.io` you must use it on the server too.

Comment: thanks Marcos. One reason why I don't want to use socket.io is because of memory leak https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2427 .

Comment: Do you have any take on that?

Comment: and Trello changed from socket.io to ws-node module http://tech.trello.com/the-trello-tech-stack/

Comment: That is a 2 years old issue, I've been using socket.io for the past 4 years, never had a problem to be honest. And when you need to scale up, and have multiple servers, if you don't use socket.io you will have a really bad time. `socket.io` has some adapters, such as `socket.io-redis` that handle all that for you.

Comment: do you have any articles that say about fixing the memory leak?

Comment: No, and that memory leak isn't confirmed, the ticket is closed. It happened on socket.io 1.x, we're on 2.x now. Try to reproduce the memory leak, if there is any. I believe you're over optimizing, which you shouldn't do. Do you plan in having a million users? `socket.io` will reduce your development time greatly.

Comment: Currently we have over 879k users and we want to implement a scalable real-time system

Comment: If you want scalable, as I said, you should probably go with `socket.io`, otherwise you will need to implement all the logic yourself.

Comment: Im just afraid of the memory leak part which i need double confirm

Comment: Just try it yourself, Haven't had any issue with it for years, and as I said, that ticket was closed.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande , I understand socket.io is easier... but it's not magic, it's just a wrapper existing technologies. I can't help feeling that you're pushing for socket.io even when the question specifically requested to avoid socket.io (`My question is what is the equivalent of socket.io function which is socket.to().emit() in ws? `)... Also, your wrapper is... well... problematic (it precludes horizontal scaling).

Comment: @Myst where in his question he asked about scaling? He asked the equivalent of `socket.to().emit()` which I have provide, and you didn't in your answer. So my response is the answer to his question. I already told him about the issue when he needed to scale in a comment.

Comment: Don't quote me on it but I believe the 'memory leak' is actually memory fragmentation that occurs from zlib, which is a module used by both ws and socket.io to compress messages before they are sent via a websocket (i.e. the problem can occur in both ws and socket.io). The compression can be disabled with `perMessageDeflate: false`, which means the zlib library would not be used and the memory fragmentation should no longer be a problem. BTW, zlib has been partially fixed (i.e. problem reduced). Also, those with large data like video may opt to compress it manually without socket.io/ws/zlib.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, the best approach is to abstract away the WebSocket using a pub/sub service.

The issue with client<=(server)=>client communication using WebSockets is that client connections are specific to the process (and machine) that "owns" the connection.

The moment your application expands beyond a single process (i.e., due to horizontal scaling requirements), the WebSocket "collection" becomes irrelevant at best. The array / dictionary in which you stored all your WebSocket connections now only stores some of the connections.

To correct approach would be to [use a pub/sub approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern), perhaps using something similar to Redis.

This allows every User to "subscribe" to a private "channel" (or "subject"). Users can subscribe to more than one "channel" (for example, a global notification channel).

To send a private message, another user "publishes" to that private "channel" - and that's it.

The pub/sub service routes the messages from the "channels" to the correct subscribers - even if they don't share the same process or the same machine.

This allows a client connected to your server in Germany to send a private message to a client connected to your server in Oregon (USA) without anyone being worried about the identity of the server / process that "owns" the connection.