# Tracking WS Clients in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, ws

I am using `ws` through an express plugin, `express-ws`. My back end needs to track clients and, send message only to a specific or clients. Right now, I am just saving the client socket along with a token. So, when the client connects, a message is sent like the following by the client:

`{"path":"/openUserSocket","token":"<CLIENT_TOKEN_VALUE>"}`

This registers a socket in the back end. The socket is managed by a class `wscManager` which, saves the socket in a plain object. So, to register a socket, I do this:

```
// adding web socket support
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app, null, {
    wsOptions: {
       clientTracking: true
    }
});
let man = new wscManager();
// then in the web socket handler
app.ws('/', (sck,req) => {
    sck.on('message',(msg)=>{
        // handle messages
        if(msg.path === '/openUserSocket'){
            man.set(msg.token, sck);
            return sck.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 200, message: 'Ok' }));
        }
        else if(msg.path === '/<SOME_OTHER_PATH>'){
             // use that socket
        }
        // ... other route handling
    }
}
```

Now, as I showed in the code above, I am trying to save the socket for later use. `set` just uses the token as a key for saving the socket object in another object. Later, `get(token)` can be used with that token to use the socket. I also extended the express app prototype to allow other route handles to use the `wscManager`:

```
app.response._man = man;
```

Now, my question is this the right approach to client tracking? In other route handlers, the manager is used like this:

```
// in route handler
res._man.send(JSON.stringify({ status: <STATUS>, message: <MSG> }));
```

Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364243/websocketserver-node-js-how-to-differentiate-clients