# Cloudflare Workers - Websocket Send Message to Client

Tags: websocket, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

In cloudflare workers we can create websockets as mentioned this blog post https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-websockets-in-workers/ but I tried to send message back to browser from server to specific client, I couldn't. I wonder how we can make something like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/17223609/9532712 with cloudflare workers.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a Durable Object: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/using-durable-objects#websockets-in-durable-objects

Comment: Not true, you can call server.send : https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/websockets