# Create Private Chat between two users using node.js in android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, socket.io

I want to create simple android application to create chat message using node.js and socket.io. I have created node.js but the problem is it is sending message to all the users who are connected to that server. I only want to have private chat between two users. For that i want to create node.js and i am newbie in that so please help me out. Here is my node.js file for all users who are connected.

```
var io  = require('socket.io');  
var server = io.listen(4732);

var macbook_socket = undefined;

server.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {  
var ipAddress = socket.handshake.address.address;
    socket.emit('chat', {name: ipAddress, text: 'joined chat'});
    //socket.emit('helo', {msg: 'welcome'});
    socket.on('user', function(data) {
        if (data.type == "client") {
            //saving socket
            macbook_socket = socket;
        }
    });


    socket.on("next", function(data) {
        console.log("received next");
        if (democlientsocket != undefined) {
            democlientsocket.emit("next", {});
        }           
    });
    socket.on('chat1', function(data){
            socket.broadcast.emit('chat1', {name: data.name, text: data.text});
      });
    socket.on("prev", function(data) {
        console.log("received prev");
        if (democlientsocket != undefined) {
            democlientsocket.emit("prev", {});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: please do not repost the question

Comment: you can use the "rooms" of Socket.io one example here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846174/dynamic-rooms-with-socket-io-and-node

Comment: Dude but it is for broadcast and for each user how many time will i have to create new room i only want application that has private chat like whatsapp.